# List iteration - item with space

Tags: list, iteration

I am trying to create a very basic static list to iterate through.  One of the values has a space in it.  I can't figure out how to add the item to the list with a space.  In the example below, I can't add trash truck in this manner.  I think there must be a special symbol I need to include.

```
<aura:iteration items="boat, car, trash truck" var="Field3">
                        <option value="{!Field3}">{!Field3}</option>
                    </aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store them in their own list of strings and then iterate over the list and you should achieve the result you're looking for

```
<aura:attribute name="vehicles" type="String[]" default="['boat','car','trash truck']"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.vehicles}" var="Field3">
    <option value="{!Field3}">{!Field3}</option>
</aura:iteration>
```